# Python Programming: Truth table

Tags: python

We have to format a truth table for p^q, pvq,p->q, and p<->q in Python.
I don't know how to format p->q or p<->q. It keeps giving me errors saying that it is an invalid syntax.  How would I include an if statement for "if p then q" and "if only p then only q."

```py
def getSym(x): 
if x: 
return 'T' 
else: 
return 'F' 

values=[True, False] 
for p in values: 
for q in values: 
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q)) 
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p or q))
```

Comment: improve your indentation

Comment: Also, don't ask us whether your code is correct; Stack Overflow is not a validation site.  Once you have a demonstrable, known problem, *then* you ask how to fix it.  If you want to know whether it works, ask the computer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Boolean implication `P => Q` is logically equivalent to `NOT P OR Q`, and Boolean equivalence `<=>` can be expressed using the equality operator `==`:

```
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p and q))    #  AND
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p or q))     #  OR
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(not p or q)) #  =>
print(getSym(p), getSym(q), getSym(p == q))     #  <=>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have a question about the formatting that we need to do for this assignment. 
https://imgur.com/Ae4f9uW < There is the link to view the table. I looked around and I could not find any guidance on how to do this formatting. Thanks!